# Java: Redirect Marshaller output to log4j

Tags: java, xml, logging, log4j, rollingfileappender

I want to make my program log the XML of the given objects using:

```
Marshaller.marshal(Object jaxbElement, OutputStream os);
```

Currently, I'm using stdout as the OutputStream. But stdout is not printed in log4j log file.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(SomeClass.class);
Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
m.marshal(input, System.out);
```

**How can I redirect the output of this method to the log4j log file?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) to create an [`OutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) and convert to a `String` with [ByteArrayOutputStream#toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toString()).

Your modified code:

```
OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(SomeClass.class);
Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
m.marshal(input, os);
String xml = os.toString();
logger.debug(xml);
```